Casl integration with Prisma and NestJS
I'm using the NestJs AuthGuard, with JwT and Casl, but I'm not understanding some concepts.
Looking for some tutorials online I did this:
My Ability Factory
import { AbilityBuilder, ExtractSubjectType, PureAbility } from '@casl/ability';
import { createPrismaAbility, PrismaQuery, Subjects } from '@casl/prisma';
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import {
  Area,
  AreaManager,
  Employee,
  Job,
  Manager,
  Metric,
  MetricScore,
  Role,
  User,
} from '@prisma/client';

export enum Action {
  Manage = 'manage',
  Create = 'create',
  Read = 'read',
  Update = 'update',
  Delete = 'delete',
}
export type Subject = {
  User: User;
  Manager: Manager;
  Area: Area;
  AreaManager: AreaManager;
  Employee: Employee;
  Metric: Metric;
  MetricScore: MetricScore;
  Role: Role;
  Job: Job;
};
type AppAbility = PureAbility<[Action, Subjects<Subject> | 'all'], PrismaQuery>;
type UserAb = User & {
  role: string;
  user: string;
};
@Injectable()
export class AbilityFactory {
  defineAbility(user: UserAb) {
    const builder = new AbilityBuilder<AppAbility>(createPrismaAbility);
    if (user.role === 'Admin') {
      builder.can(Action.Manage, 'all');
    }
    if (user.role == 'Gerente') {
      builder.can(Action.Read, 'User', { id: user.user });
      builder.can(Action.Update, 'User', { id: user.user });
      builder.can(Action.Manage, 'Employee', {
        ManagerEmployee: { manager_id: { equals: user.user } },
      });
      builder.can(Action.Read, 'Manager', {
        user_id: {
          equals: user.user,
        },
      });
      builder.can(Action.Update, 'Manager', {
        user_id: {
          equals: user.user,
        },
      });
      builder.can(Action.Manage, 'Job', {
        area: {
          some: {
            managers: {
              some: {
                manager_id: user.user,
              },
            },
          },
        },
      });
      builder.can(Action.Manage, 'Metric');
      builder.can(Action.Manage, 'MetricScore', {
        employee: {
          ManagerEmployee: {
            manager_id: {
              equals: user.user,
            },
          },
        },
      });
    }
    if (user.role === 'TI') {
      builder.can(Action.Manage, 'User');
      builder.can(Action.Manage, 'Role');
    }

    const ability = builder.build();
    return ability;
  }
}

My Ability Guard
```
@Injectable()
export class AbilityGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(
    private reflector: Reflector,
    private caslAbilityFactory: AbilityFactory,
  ) {}
  async canActivate(context: ExecutionContext): Promise<boolean> {
    const rules =
      this.reflector.get<RequiredRule[]>(
        'check_ability',
        context.getHandler(),
      ) || [];
    const req = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
    const ability = this.caslAbilityFactory.defineAbility(req.user);
    try {
      rules.forEach((rule) => {
        ForbiddenError.from(ability).throwUnlessCan(rule.action, rule.subject);
      });
      return true;
    } catch (e) {
      if (e instanceof ForbiddenError) {
        throw new ForbiddenException(e.message);
      }
    }
    return true;
  }
}

```
The controller
```
@UseGuards(JwTGuard, AbilityGuard)
@Controller('manager')
export class ManagerController {
  constructor(private managerService: ManagerService) {}
  @Get(':id')
  getManagerById(@Param('id') id: string) {
    return this.managerService.getManagerById(id);
  }

  @Post(':id/addemployee')
  addManagerEmployee(@Param('id') id: string, @Body() dto: AddEmployee) {
    return this.managerService.addManagerEmployee(id, dto);
  }
  @Get('jobs')
  getAllJobs(@GetUser('user') id: string) {
    return this.managerService.getAllJobs(id);
  }
  @CheckAbilities({ action: Action.Read, subject: 'Job' })
  @Get('jobs/:id')
  getJobById(@Param('id') id: string, @GetUser('user') user_id: string) {
    return this.managerService.getJobById(user_id, id);
  }
}

```
The app that i'm building requires that the admin have the access to everthing, but the managers can only have access to the rows that they are refered, but when using the casl aproach this part
builder.can(Action.Manage, 'Job', {
        area: {
          some: {
            managers: {
              some: {
                manager_id: user.user,
              },
            },
          },
        },
      });`

It's not working as I expected. What am I doing wrong?
